# Contradiction in tensor notation

Tags: tensors

I have defined a 3 component second order tensor as such:

$$Q_{ij} = S_{ij} - S_{ii}\delta_{ij}$$

Where $\delta_{ij}$ is the kronecker-delta. 
If I choose a constant index, for example $i = j = 1$, I find the following:
$$Q_{11} = S_{11} - S_{11}\delta_{11}\\ = S_{11} - S_{11}\\ = 0 $$

This will hold for the other 2 components, i.e. $i=j=2$ and $i=j=2$. This means the following:

$$Tr(Q) = Q_{11} + Q_{22} + Q_{33} = 0$$

**However**, if i choose $i=j=k$, where k is a dummy index, we will have:

$$Tr(Q) \equiv Q_{kk} = S_{kk} - S_{kk}\delta_{kk}\\ = S_{kk} - 3S_{kk}\\ = -2S_{kk}$$

which need not be zero if the $Tr(S) \neq 0$. Thus the contradiction.

Can anyone clarify if I have a loophole in my logic somewhere?

Comment: Can you talk us about the equality: $S_{kk}-S_{kk}\delta_{kk}=S_{kk}-3S_{kk}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using indicial (Einstein) notation you must have an equal number of free indices on both sides of your equation. For your case on the LHS you have $i$ and $j$ as the free indices but on the RHS you have $j$ as a free index and $i$ (probably) the dummy index. So maybe if you mean $S_{ii}$ as the trace of $\bf{S}$ you must have said:

$$Q_{ij} = S_{ij}-S_{kk}\delta_{ij}$$

So take $i=j=1$

$$Q_{11} = S_{11}-(S_{11}+S_{22}+S_{33})\delta_{11} = -S_{22}-S_{33}$$

and $i=j=2$

$$Q_{22} = S_{22}-(S_{11}+S_{22}+S_{33})\delta_{22} = -S_{11}-S_{33}$$

and $i=j=3$

$$Q_{33} = S_{33}-(S_{11}+S_{22}+S_{33})\delta_{33} = -S_{11}-S_{22}$$

if you sum them up:

$$Q_{11}+Q_{22}+Q_{33} = -2S_{11}-2S_{22}-2S_{33} = -2\text{tr}(\bf{S})$$

or in general

$$Q_{ii} = S_{ii} - S_{kk}\delta_{ii} = S_{ii} - 3S_{kk} = -2S_{ii}$$

$$\text{tr}(\textbf{Q}) = \text{tr}(\textbf{S}) - \text{tr}(\textbf{S})\text{tr}(\textbf{I}) = -2\text{tr}(\textbf{S})$$

Comment: Is this the equivalent of saying that my earlier defined Q does not count as a tensor because it does not transform like a second order tensor?

Comment: The defined $\textbf{Q}$ on the LHS IS a tensor so complies with tensor rules if you mean $\text{trace}(\textbf{S})$ by $S_{ii}$ (For example, it can be deviatoric stress tensor in Analytical Mechanics). If so, the way you have assigned the indices does not comply with the indicial notation rules.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't sum when you wrote $Q_{kk}$. You should have $\sum_k S_{kk} - S_{kk} \delta_{kk}=\sum_k 0$. Presumably you're using Einstein notation, but that *still* means you need to do the implicit summations required by that notation.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by implicit summations?